# Frechet distance example

Tags: complex-analysis, frechet-derivative, hausdorff-distance

I'm new in such things like Frechet Distance. So I want a simple example with real data with "writing on paper" every step. Then I will do the same through the coding. But before, I need to understand that.

1. $P,Q$ - 2 curves. Where P is a man and Q is a dog
   Let's imagine I have (latitude,longitude) or anything else. Just numbers:

   - $(22.3, 13.4)$, $(23.4, 12.5)$, $(25.3, 11.7) $ belonging to Person curve
   - $(13.3, 34.6)$, $(14.4, 33.3)$, $(17.4, 19.6) $ belonging to Dog curve
2. "Person follows a path of points $p_1, \ldots ,p_n$" - Can we say that every () in previous line indicates points? Ex:

   - $(22.3, 13.4)$ - $p_1$
   - $(23.4, 12.5)$ - $p_2$
   - $\ldots$
   - $(25.3, 11.7)$ - $p_n$
     and
   - $(13.3, 34.6)$ - $q_1$
   - $(14.4, 33.3)$ - $q_2$
   - $\ldots$
   - $(17.4, 19.6)$ - $q_n$
3. Person and the Dog are doing steps:

   - $p_i$ to $p_{i+1}$ - person
   - $q_i$ to $q_{i+1}$ - dog
     What is that in term if numbers? Where I get them?
4. $L(i,j)$ Frechet distance - smallest distance and etc.
5. $d(p, q)$ distance between 2 point. Which points? () () () - "from 1)" between them?

After all, we need to satisfy following condition to find Frechet/min distance:
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVjg1.png)

Where do we get that i and j in our dataset?

Can I get simple example with 2 rows I have provided? Thanks! Sorry for such simplification

For example when I was studying Euclidean Distance I found video on youtube by simple matrix. So I need that simple explanation here too. Thanks!

PDF to Frechet
http://www2.compute.dtu.dk/courses/02110/diverse/exex.pdf